# When exposing an API, is there a good way to enable the ability to call previous versions of the API?

Tags: python, api-design

How can I create an API that allows users to specify which version of the backend Python script processing the calculations uses? For example, if my API accepts one parameter x, and API v1 returns `x * 2`, and API v2 returns `x * 3`, could the user specify that they wanted version 1 or 2? Of course, I could add a parameter to the API that is 'v1' and an if statement in the Python code, but that seems error-prone and unwieldy after many iterations.

Further, I'd like the API to respond with the value, and also the API version.

Is there a common way to approach this situation? Basically, I'm looking to deploy an API with reproducible and verifiable results from prior iterations of the same API endpoint.

I wasn't sure the best way to word the question, maybe someone can edit the title later if there's a better description of what I asked

Comment: It's very common to provide versioned api endpoints (like `/api/v1` and `/api/v2`).

Comment: @larsks thanks. so would it be reasonable to have `/api/` return the most recent version, and in the response, I could include the version. So if a user wanted to recalculate a request that was sent in the past, they could use `/api/v#/` to get the same output (assuming the API has been updated since they submitted the original request)

Comment: I think you always want to use the versioned url (because this way you don't need to update your clients because `/api` is no longer the API they expect), but at this point we've clearly ventured into the realm of opinions.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best practice to version the api endpoints. In that way you don't cause breaking changes or unexpected behaviour for consumers of your api. For example, if you have consumers of the endpoint (including your test suite) just using /api/ and they have always got the answer 2 and suddenly it's now 3 that could cause unexpected behaviour in their system. With versioning you keep all that clean and can develop your new features knowing you're not going to impact all existing consumers and forcing everyone to migrate at the same time. Hope this helps!